# Getting world position in post processing vertex shader

Tags: three.js

I am working on a post processing shader in three.js where I need to discard some fragment based on calculation from the world position in the vertex shader.

When I tried to do it in the vertex shader, I found that the position passed in the vertex shader is already transformed into screen space coordinate ie. the projection, view and model matrices are identity.

Is there a way to get the original position attribute in world coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing vertex position in screen space you can pass ModelView and Projection Matrix in vertex shader and calculate screen space position in shader itself. Usually this multiplication is done on CPU because of performance resons. OR if you have these matrices in shader already then you can multiply vertex psition with inverse of projection matrix and you will get vertex position in world coordinates. I dont understand what do you mean by saying matrices are identity.